# custom listview doesn't get populated

Tags: android

My layout is divided into 4 parts, each with same layout. 4 relative layouts with one image view, textview and listview each. The layout can be considered to be like a 2x2 grid with a custom layout with one imageview, textview and listview. The listview consists of 2 textviews. I have an ArrayAdapter<> to use with the listview. I have the data for listview in one data structure which I pass to the adapter. When i run the application, the listview area of the layout is blank where as the imageview and textview are displayed. I tried debugging the issue and found out that getView of the adapter is not getting called.

The layout will look like this. The portion below application1 and below is where the listview shuld come.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rNYV.png

Main layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/app1"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="250dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/app1Img"
            android:layout_width="175dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/app1Data"
            android:background="@color/blue"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/app1Heading"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_below="@id/app1Img"
            android:paddingLeft="25dip"
            android:background="@color/color2"/>
        <ListView android:id="@+id/app1Data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dip"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/app2"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="250dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/app2Img"
            android:layout_width="175dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/blue"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/app2Heading"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/app2Img"
            android:paddingLeft="25dip"
            android:background="@color/color2"/>

        <ListView android:id="@+id/app2Data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@id/app2Heading"
            android:background="@color/color3">
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/app3"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="250dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/app1">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/app3Img"
            android:layout_width="175dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/blue"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/app3Heading"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/app3Img"
            android:paddingLeft="25dip"
            android:background="@color/color2"/>

        <ListView android:id="@+id/app3Data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@id/app3Heading"
            android:background="@color/color3">
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/app4"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="250dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/app2">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/app4Img"
            android:layout_width="175dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/blue"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/app4Heading"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/app4Img"
            android:paddingLeft="25dip"
            android:background="@color/color2"/>

        <ListView android:id="@+id/app4Data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@id/app4Heading"
            android:background="@color/color3">
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Listview layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <TextView android:id="@+id/mainText"
android:layout_width="150dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/subscript"
android:layout_width="150dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:lines="2"
android:singleLine="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Main activity:

```
TextView app1Header;
ImageView app1Img;
ListView app1Data;


TextView app2Header;
ImageView app2Img;
ListView app2Data;


TextView app3Header;
ImageView app3Img;
ListView app3Data;


TextView app4Header;
ImageView app4Img;
ListView app4Data;

    ApplicationData applicationData = _allApplicationData.get(0);
    app1Header.setText(applicationData.mHeadlineText);
    ArrayList<DashboardListItem> application1ListItems = new ArrayList<DashboardListItem>();
    DashboardListItem application1ListItem1 = new DashboardListItem();
    DashboardListItem application1ListItem2 = new DashboardListItem();
    application1ListItem1.mainText = getApplicationMainTextForRow(0, applicationData.mApplicationName, _organization);
    application1ListItem1.subscript = getApplicationSubscriptForRow(0, applicationData.mApplicationName, _organization);
    application1ListItems.add(application1ListItem1);
    application1ListItem2.mainText = getApplicationMainTextForRow(1, applicationData.mApplicationName, _organization);
    application1ListItem2.subscript = getApplicationSubscriptForRow(1, applicationData.mApplicationName, _organization);
    application1ListItems.add(application1ListItem2);
    DashboardListAdapter application1Adapter = new DashboardListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.dashboardlist, application1ListItems);
    app1Data.setAdapter(application1Adapter);

    applicationData = _allApplicationData.get(1);
    app2Header.setText(applicationData.mHeadlineText);
    ArrayList<DashboardListItem> application2ListItems = new ArrayList<DashboardListItem>();
    DashboardListItem application2ListItem = new DashboardListItem();
    application2ListItem.mainText = getApplicationMainTextForRow(0, applicationData.mApplicationName, _organization);
    application2ListItem.subscript = getApplicationSubscriptForRow(0, applicationData.mApplicationName, _organization);
    application2ListItems.add(application2ListItem);
    DashboardListAdapter application2Adapter = new DashboardListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.dashboardlist, application2ListItems);
    app2Data.setAdapter(application2Adapter);

    applicationData = _allApplicationData.get(2);
    app3Header.setText(applicationData.mHeadlineText);
    ArrayList<DashboardListItem> application3ListItems = new ArrayList<DashboardListItem>();
    DashboardListItem application3ListItem = new DashboardListItem();
    application3ListItem.mainText = getApplicationMainTextForRow(0, applicationData.mApplicationName, _organization);
    application3ListItem.subscript = getApplicationSubscriptForRow(0, applicationData.mApplicationName, _organization);
    application3ListItems.add(application3ListItem);
    DashboardListAdapter application3Adapter = new DashboardListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.dashboardlist, application3ListItems);
    app3Data.setAdapter(application3Adapter);

    applicationData = _allApplicationData.get(3);
    app4Header.setText(applicationData.mHeadlineText);
    ArrayList<DashboardListItem> application4ListItems = new ArrayList<DashboardListItem>();
    DashboardListItem application4ListItem = new DashboardListItem();
    application4ListItem.mainText = getApplicationMainTextForRow(0, applicationData.mApplicationName, _organization);
    application4ListItem.subscript = getApplicationSubscriptForRow(0, applicationData.mApplicationName, _organization);
    application4ListItems.add(application4ListItem);
    DashboardListAdapter application4Adapter = new DashboardListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.dashboardlist, application4ListItems);
    app4Data.setAdapter(application4Adapter);
```

Adapter file:

```
public class DashboardListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DashboardListItem>{

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<DashboardListItem> dashBoardData;
int resource;

public DashboardListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<DashboardListItem> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mContext = context;
    resource = textViewResourceId;
    dashBoardData = objects;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public DashboardListItem getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = convertView;
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        v = vi.inflate(resource,null);
    } 
    //DashboardListItem appData = dashBoardData.get(position);
    DashboardListItem listItem = dashBoardData.get(position);
    TextView mainText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mainText);
    TextView subscript = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.subscript);

    mainText.setText(listItem.mainText);
    subscript.setText(listItem.subscript);
    return convertView;
}
```

}

I am not getting any error while compiling or running the application. Just that getView() is not getting called. The arraylist of data to be passed to the adapter are populated and passed manually so as to make sure the data is populated for sure. I've checked from logs that data is not null/empty.

I am badly stuck with this. I tried to search a lot but i'm still unable to find why getView() doesn't get called.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the problem. It was my mistake. In adapter getview i was doing 2 mistakes. One was inflating the view using resources i pass on to the constructor instead of directly referring to the layout using R. The second one is I was inflating it to view v where as I was returning convert view. Thanks for ur time and help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.setDatasetChanged()` at the point where you want to show the data to tell the listview to populate.

And I think you should set text `dashBoardData.get(position)` from the List you've passed to the constructor.

And where you instantiate the listview from the xml? I dont see it anywhere in your code

You MUST do this to get the list populated (this applies for all your listviews)

```
ListView app1Data = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.app1Data);  // <--- This is what might be causing your issue.
```

Comment: Thanks Nikola for the response. I do have the code to instantiate listview from xml in onCreate() of MainActivity.I'm setting the text from the lost i passed to the constructor. This is done in getView().
 DashboardListItem listItem = dashBoardData.get(position);

    mainText.setText(listItem.mainText);
    subscript.setText(listItem.subscript);
I added adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in my mainactivity after adding data to the adapter. Still listview doesn't get populated.

Comment: I found the solution to the problem. It was my mistake. In adapter getview i was doing 2 mistakes. One was inflating the view using resources i pass on to the constructor instead of directly referring to the layout using R. The second one is I was inflating it to view v where as I was returning convert view. Thanks for ur time and help anyways.